# Kubernetes (AKS) - how to load balance both TCP and UDP ports for same IP address

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress, wowza, azure-aks

We want to run a Wowza streaming engine among other containers in our Kubernetes cluster on Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS). Wowza uses various ports, some with TCP, some with UDP protocol.

We need to expose these ports to the outside world. We can't seem to find a way to set up a load balancer that can forward both TCP and UDP ports.

A LoadBalancer service does not support mixed protocols until an upcoming version of K8s, and it will be even longer until this version is available in AKS: [link](https://github.com/kubernetes/enhancements/issues/1435)

We have tried using nginx-ingress, but it has the same limitation due to the underlying K8s limitation: see comment from author [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/6573)

It would seem like citrix-ingress allows this according to its documentation, but we have a lot of problems making it work at all...

Is there any way to do this that we may have missed? Want to make sure we are not missing something obvious.

Answer (score 1):

This is a community wiki answer posted for better visibility. Feel free to edit it when the final solution would be available (k8s v1.20 on AKS).

There is an open enhancement: [Support of mixed protocols in Services with type=LoadBalancer #1435](https://github.com/kubernetes/enhancements/issues/1435) which when implemented will enable the creation of a `LoadBalancer` Service that has different port definitions with different protocols. The stable release is planned for k8s v1.20.

Unfortunately, it is not possible to use both TCP and UDP ports with `LoadBalancer` Service currently. It would be however when the above solution is in place.

Comment: Update on this: while the required feature has made it into k8s v1.20, it is guarded by a feature flag. AFAIK, AKS does not allow enabling feature flags. Furthermore, the feature is in alpha state and seeing how some other k8s features have been in alpha for years, we're not exactly optimistic about this being enabled by default on AKS anytime soon.

In light of this, we have actually given up for now. It doesn't seem like there's any way to run Wowza in k8s on AKS.

Comment: Alpha gate support is planned as of Jan 14, but as usual it has no delivery date. https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/2058

Answer (score 0):

You can run your pods with hostNetwork mode and then manually set up a load balancer on top of that or similar. This is not recommended both for security and automation reasons.

Comment: @user1236689 Does this solves your issue?

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor, no, as coderanger said, that solution is not recommended. We have not found any solution, so we will be hosting Wowza separately from our K8s cluster until the 1.20 version is available on Azure Kubernetes Service.